# How do I handle PromiseRejectionHandledWarning in unit tests?

Tags: node.js, es6-promise, sinon

Consider this awful function which nevertheless serves as a simulacrum of my real problem:

```
async function rejectingFunction() {
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 10000000));
    throw new Error("Boom");
}
```

Now, I need to write some unit tests for it. I don't want to wait however long that random number I put in is, so I'll also use the `sinon` library's ability to fake timers to do the testing:

```
describe("test suite", () => {
    it("should reject", async () => {
        const timers = sinon.useFakeTimers();
        let threw = false;

        try {
            const promise = rejectingFunction();
            await timers.runAllAsync();          // this is required for setTimeout to resolve
            await promise;                       // trap the rejection
        } catch (e) {
            threw = true;
            should.equal("Boom", e.message);
        } finally {
            timers.restore();
        }

        should(threw).be.true();
    });
});
```

Easy enough (ignore the clunky "did not throw" detection, that's not the point here...). But, let's run the test to be sure:

```
test suite
    ✔ should reject
(node:7319) PromiseRejectionHandledWarning: Promise rejection was handled asynchronously (rejection id: 1)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)


1 passing (9ms)
```

The test passed, and didn't take forever, but we get an unwanted warning. I understand why it is happening (I had neither a catch handler, nor an await in play at the time that the rejection happened), but in this case the behaviour is expected.

Is there some way to indicate that it's okay for the rejection to happen, and I promise I will get to it shortly? I've tried adding an empty catch handler, but that just turns the rejection into a resolution, which isn't what I want. I also tried adding a catch handler that throws just kicks moves the source of the warning. I also can't await on the promise before I run `timers.runAllAsync()`, or else it will hang because the clock is paused.

Answer (score 0):

How about chaining a `catch` handler directly to the `rejectingFunction` invocation? As in:

```
const timers = sinon.useFakeTimers();
let threw = false;

const promise = rejectingFunction().catch((e) => {
  threw = true;
  should.equal("Boom", e.message);
});

await timers.runAllAsync();
await promise;

timers.restore();

should(threw).be.true();
```